# How to download a live MySQL db into a local test db on demand, without SSH?

Tags: php, ruby, database, mysql

I have a fairly small MySQL database (a Textpattern install) on a server that I do not have SSH access to (I have FTP access only). I need to regularly download the live database to my local dev server on demand; i.e., I would like to either run a script and/or have a cron job running. What are some good ways of doing this?

Some points to note:

- Live server is running Linux, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2 and MySQL 4.1
- Local server is running the same (so using PHP is an option), but the OS is Windows
- Local server has Ruby on it (so using Ruby is a valid option)
- The live MySQL db *can* accept remote connections from different IPs
- I cannot enable replication on the remote server

***Update:*** I've accepted BlaM's answer; it is beautifully simple. Can't believe I didn't think of that. There was one problem, though: I wanted to automate the process, but the proposed solution prompts the user for a password. Here is a slightly modified version of the mysqldump command that passes in the password:

`mysqldump -u USER --password=MYPASSWORD DATABASE_TO_DUMP -h HOST > backup.sql`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can access your database remotely, you can use mysqldump from your windows machine to fetch the remote database. From commandline:

```
cd "into mysql directory"
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p -h YOUR_HOST_IP DATABASE_TO_MIRROR >c:\backup\database.sql
```

The program will ask you for the database password and then generate a file c:\backup\database.sql that you can run on your windows machine to insert the data.

With a small database that should be fairly fast.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use. This dumps the database from the live server while uploads it to the local server.
`mysqldump -hlive_server_addresss -ulive_server_user -plive_server_password --opt --compress live_server_db | mysql -ulocal_server_user -plocal_server_password local_server_db`

You can run this from a **bat** file. You can ever use a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

Is MySQL replication an option?  You could even turn it on and off if you didn't want it constantly replicating.

This was a [good article](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication) on replication.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a (Ruby) script to do a `SELECT * FROM ...` on all the databases on the server and then do a `DROP DATABASE ...` followed by a series of new `INSERT`s on the local copy. You can do a `SHOW DATABASES` query to list the databases dynamically. Now, this assumes that the table structure doesn't change, but if you want to support table changes also you could add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` query and a corresponding `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table in each database. To get a list of all the tables in a database you do a `SHOW TABLES` query.

Once you have the script you can set it up as a scheduled job to run as often as you need.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Biek

> Is MySQL replication an option? You could even turn it on and off if you didn't want it constantly replicating.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot enable replication on the server. It is a shared server with very little room for maneuver. I've updated the question to note this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you need to copy down live data and how quickly you need to do it, installing [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) on both machines might be an option.  You can export and import DBs, but you'd have to do it manually.  If it's a small DB (and it sounds like it is), and you don't need live data copied over too often, it might work well for what you need.